How to get conditional return types in react query
I have a common method to use useQuery or useMutation based on the HTTP method as prop. But the return type of this method is containing 'QueryObserverRefetchErrorResult<any, Error>' which doesn't have methods included in useMutation or useQuery.
I tried conditional types such as but the issue was same.
type ResultType<Method extends NTWRK_METHODS> = Method extends NTWRK_METHODS.GET ? NetworkQueryResult : NetworkMutationResult;


My method is

type NetworkQueryResult = UseQueryResult<any, Error>;
type NetworkMutationResult = UseMutationResult<any, Error, void, unknown>;

export function useNetworkQuery(
  props: IUseNetworkCallWithClient,
): NetworkQueryResult | NetworkMutationResult {
  const {queryKey, axiosClient, url, persist, method, params = ''} = props;

  if (method === NTWRK_METHODS.GET) {
    return useQuery({
      queryKey: [queryKey],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const data = await axiosClient.request({
          method: NTWRK_METHODS.GET,
          url: url,
          params: params,
        });
        return data.data;
      },
      enabled: false,
      meta: {persist},
    });
  } else {
    return useMutation({
      mutationKey: [queryKey],
      mutationFn: async () => {
        const data = await axiosClient.request({
          method: method,
          url: url,
          data: params,
        });
        return data.data;
      },
      meta: {persist},
    });
  }
} 


I am calling it as

export const makeNetworkCall = (props: IUseNetworkCallWithoutClient) => {
  const {method, queryKey, url, persist, params = ''} = props;
  const config = {
    axiosClient,
    queryKey: queryKey,
    method: method,
    url: url,
    persist: persist,
    params: params,
  };

  return useNetworkQuery(config);
};


and then
export const useAuthCalls = () => {
  const logIn = () => {
    makeNetworkCall({
      method: NTWRK_METHODS.POST,
      url: '/users',
      queryKey: 'login',
      persist: true,
      params: '',
    });
  };

  return {logIn};
};



Quick questions. Is NTWRK_METHODS an enum? The last two code snippets are exactly the same, was this a mistake? Are makeNetworkCall and useNetworkQuery the same functions or are they different?

yes its a enum and the repeated code was mistake, edited and fixed.

A little sidenote, as how I see how you're defining these functions, especially makeNetworkCall (which does not have a use prefix but still is a hook), you might be tempted to call these in action handlers (for example a button's onClick). Keep in mind they're still hooks and must be always called in the same order all the time when rendering in a React component. If you tried to call your logIn method when clicking a button for example, you'd probably get a warning, if not an actual error.

You are correct, and thanks for correcting me, i was indeed getting a warning. By same order you mean i should call the logIn method and then makeNetworkCall and then usenetworkquery?

No, same order implies that hooks should be called always when rendering a component. As in, you should not conditionally call hooks. Calling a hook from an action handler is by definition conditional because it will be only called if a button is clicked. Your current implementation has a flawed design because in order to avoid this warning you would have to call login every time your component is re-rendered.

What's more, useMutation does not actually run the request when called, it returns a mutate and mutateAsync functions that can be used to actually run the request. These are the ones you should use in your action handlers, not the actual useMutation.

Got it, i should run the hook at render and maybe use mutate as a reusable method. Totally forgot the rule of not to conditionally call the hook.

Despite what we discussed earlier in the comments I'll give you an answer regarding the typing of your useNetworkQuery function which is pretty much what you're asking in this post.

What you need here is function overloading to help differentiate what is being returned by useNetworkQuery.
Simply defining the return type of your function as NetworkQueryResult | NetworkMutationResult will not work well enough because TypeScript won't be able to tell which of these two is the one returned, only that whatever is returned could be either one of these "so treat them as if they were both".
How about replacing your useNetworkQuery to this?
export function useNetworkQuery<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error>(props: Exclude<IUseNetworkCallWithClient, "method"> & { method: NTWRK_METHODS.GET; }): UseQueryResult<TData, TError>;
export function useNetworkQuery<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error, TVariables = any>(props: Exclude<IUseNetworkCallWithClient, "method"> & { method: Exclude<NTWRK_METHODS, NTWRK_METHODS.GET>; }): UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables>;
export function useNetworkQuery<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error, TVariables = any>(props: IUseNetworkCallWithClient): UseQueryResult<TData, TError> | UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables> {
  const { queryKey, axiosClient, url, persist, method, params = "" } = props;

  if (method === NTWRK_METHODS.GET) {
    return useQuery<TData, TError>({
      queryKey: [queryKey],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const data = await axiosClient.request({
          method: NTWRK_METHODS.GET,
          url: url,
          params: params,
        });
        return data.data;
      },
      enabled: false,
      meta: { persist },
    });
  }

  return useMutation<TData, TError, TVariables>({
    mutationKey: [queryKey],
    mutationFn: async () => {
      const data = await axiosClient.request({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: params,
      });
      return data.data;
    },
    meta: { persist },
  });
}

A little explanation regarding this:

We overload the function with 2 signatures that change the return type to UseQueryResult<TData, TError> if the given props includes a method property equal to NTWRK_METHODS.GET or changes it to UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables> for any other NTWRK_METHODS that is not NTWRK_METHODS.GET.
We add generics to the function for TData, TError, and TVariables which are generics accepted by the useQuery and useMutation functions. This way, your useNetworkQuery function can keep the correct typing behavior instead of making everything be set to any.


The previous function should work well enough, but what about makeNetworkCall? If you try to return useNetworkQuery directly you'll notice you'll get an error saying that the implementation call signature is not externally visible. That's because when you overload a function, only the overload signatures are the ones that are taken into account calling the function and the implementation one serves only for the implementation.
You should then add an extra overload to useNetworkQuery:
export function useNetworkQuery<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error, TVariables = any>(props: IUseNetworkCallWithClient): UseQueryResult<TData, TError> | UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables>;

Which is basically the same signature as the implementation one.
Now, you can overload your makeNetworkCall function:
export function makeNetworkCall<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error>(props: Exclude<IUseNetworkCallWithClient, "method"> & { method: NTWRK_METHODS.GET; }): UseQueryResult<TData, TError>;
export function makeNetworkCall<TData = any, TError extends Error = Error, TVariables = any>(props: Exclude<IUseNetworkCallWithClient, "method"> & { method: Exclude<NTWRK_METHODS, NTWRK_METHODS.GET>; }): UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables>;
export function makeNetworkCall<TData = any,TError extends Error = Error,TVariables = any>(props: IUseNetworkCallWithClient): UseQueryResult<TData, TError> | UseMutationResult<TData, TError, TVariables>;
export function makeNetworkCall(props: IUseNetworkCallWithoutClient) {
  const { method, queryKey, url, persist, params = "" } = props;
  const config = {
    axiosClient,
    queryKey: queryKey,
    method: method,
    url: url,
    persist: persist,
    params: params,
  };

  return useNetworkQuery(config);
}


Finally, you can call your makeNetworkCall hook from your components:
const getQuery = makeNetworkCall({ method: NTWRK_METHODS.GET }); // Type is UseQueryResult.
const postQuery = makeNetworkCall({ method: NTWRK_METHODS.POST }); // Type is UseMutationResult.


As a sidenote regarding the useAuthCalls hook...
How about replacing it with:
export const useAuthCalls = () => {
  const logInMutation = makeNetworkCall({
    method: NTWRK_METHODS.POST,
    url: "/users",
    queryKey: "login",
    persist: true,
    params: "",
  });

  return {
    logIn: logInMutation.mutateAsync,
  };
};

This way, you're always using the makeNetworkCall hook and only returning the mutateAsync for the logIn call. You should be able to call this from your action handlers with no problem.
As a suggestion, rename your makeNetworkCall to something that starts with use. The reason for this is to remind you that this is in fact a hook and should be treated as one. Meaning, it should always be called in order and only inside React components.
If it helps you visualize this better, here's a CodeSandbox that you can check out:


This worked perfetcly fine, but i later realised it is not best practice to use hooks in conditional statements, so now i am using two different methods. The solution you gave was correct though
